# RSpecでRubyの標準入出力をテストする方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

RSpecでRubyの標準入出力をテストするにはどうすればいいのでしょうか？

テスト対象は以下のようなコードです。

```ruby
class Sample

  def run
    puts 'Please input your name'

    while input = STDIN.gets.chomp
      break if input == "exit"
      puts "Your name is #{input}"
      puts 'Please input your name'
    end
  end
end

Sample.new.run
```

実行すると名前入力を受け付けて、入力があれば名前を表示し、また名前受付に戻る処理をループで繰り返します。exitで処理を抜けます。

```ruby
$ ruby test.rb
Please input your name
Taro
Your name is Taro
Please input your name
Jiro
Your name is Jiro
Please input your name
exit
```

このRSpecテストコードを書いているのですが無限ループに入ってしまって、どうしてもできません。

```ruby
describe Sample do
  describe 'run' do

    let(:sample) { Sample.new }

    it 'puts your name' do
      allow(STDIN).to receive(:gets) { 'Takashi' }
      expect(STDOUT).to receive(:puts).with('Please input your name')
      sample.run
    end
  end
end
```

やりたいテストはTakashiと入れた場合はYour name is Takashiと出たら成功。
exitと入れた場合は処理を抜ける、のテストです。

どのようにすればいいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

まず、test.rb の最終行を次のようにします。テスト時に `Sample.new.run` が実行されないようにするためです。

```
Sample.new.run if $0 == __FILE__
```

また、今のテストコードでは `STDIN.gets` が 'Takashi' しか返しません。
1回目に 'Takashi'、2回目に 'exit' を返すようにします。

```
allow(STDIN).to receive(:gets).and_return 'Takashi', 'exit'
```

そして、`STDOUT.puts` が 'Please input your name' しか期待していないので、
`Please input your name` や `Your name is Takashi` も受け取れるようにします。

```
expect(STDOUT).to receive(:puts).with('Please input your name')
expect(STDOUT).to receive(:puts).with('Your name is Takashi')
expect(STDOUT).to receive(:puts).with('Please input your name')
```

これで動くと思います。